# Is it possible to chain mappers using mapstruct

Tags: java, mapping, mapstruct

I have 3 classes : A, B and C

and some mappers : A -> B -> C

I want to create a third mapper (A -> C) that use the first two.

```java
@Mapper
public abstract class TestMapper {

    public abstract B toB(A a);
    public abstract C toC(B b);

    public abstract C toC(A a); // How to chain existing mapper methods ?
/*
    // Expected implementation
    public C toC(A a) {
        C c = toC(toB(a));
        additionalStuff(a, c);
        return c;
    }
*/

    @AfterMapping
    protected void additionalStuff(A a, @MappingTarget B b) {
        // some mapping logic
    }

    @AfterMapping
    protected void additionalStuff(A a, @MappingTarget C c) {
        // some mapping logic
    }
}
```

I don't want to rewrite the mapper from A to C and prefer reuse the existing one because A to B is  a bit complex (so A to C also) but reusing the existing methods will be quite simple.

I can write the expected implementation by myself but I think it's a pity.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a feature for that, but you can do it on your own:

BMapper:

```
@Mapper
public abstract class BMapper {
    
    BMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(BMapper.class);

    public abstract B toB(A a);
        
    @AfterMapping
    protected void additionalStuff(A a, @MappingTarget B b) {
        // some additional mapping logic
    }

}
```

CMapper:

```
@Mapper
public abstract class CMapper {
    
    CMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(CMapper.class);

    public abstract C toC(B b);

    public C toC(A a) {
        C c = toC(BMapper.INSTANCE.toB(a));
        additionalStuff(a, c);
        return c;
    }

    private void additionalStuff(A a, C c) {
        // some additional mapping logic
    }

}
```

Documentation:
[Adding custom methods to mappers](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#adding-custom-methods)

Personal opinion:
This can be a bit confusing, so it would be better to have a direct mapping between a and c.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Spliting the methods in 2 different classes does not change the original request (and your example is very close to what I currently have but I wanted to simplify the example as possible to clearly explain my point).
If I want to do that way is because the BMapper and CMapper are in 2 different projects and I don't want to rewrite the BMapper logic (that is complex). I want to reuse existing methods and only add missing mapping in order to avoid duplicate code, potential bugs and reduce the complexity and maintenance cost.